# Dynamically Create Linked List in C

Tags: c, dynamic, linked-list

In Header File:

```
struct myStruct{
  int data;
  struct myStruct *next;
};

typedef struct myStruct myStruct;
```

Relative Function:

```
myStruct * create(){
  myStruct * a = NULL;
  int size;
  printf("Enter Size of List : ");
  scanf("%d",&size);

  for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){
  /*
   * can't seem to figure out how to do this correctly.
   * 
   * I know I have to use malloc(sizeof()),etc..
   *
   * I've only had success with creating the list backwards.
   * 
   * In this loop there would be a scan from user input for 
   *      the data instance
   */
  }
return a;
}
```

So I think that's pretty straightforward. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this 'myStruct a = NULL' compile? If so, I'm surprised.

Comment: Sorry, I was doing this from memory (not copy-paste). 'a' is a pointer...edited

Comment: Inside your loop, ask the user for number. Allocate one myStruct with malloc and set the data field to the number from the user. Keep track of the most recent item in the list and use this to set the next pointer. Then set the most recent item to the one you just allocated. Good luck.

Comment: Makes sense (on to implementing)...thanks for the help

Comment: Another possibility is creating the list backwards and then reversing it when you are done. This technique is common in functional languages where you are not allowed to mutate a list node after you create it.

Comment: You can also do this with a ptr-to-ptr that holds the address of the next pointer to populate in the list. It makes for an elegant and rather brief insertion loop.

Comment: I think this question should be closed because it a request to write a whole program with parts that the author didn't address such as user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
// Get user input and store it in the list
void getValue(myStruct *ptr)
{
    printf("\nEnter Data:");
    scanf("%d",&ptr->data);
    ptr->next=NULL;
}

myStruct * create()
{
   myStruct * a_head = NULL;  // start of list
   myStruct * a_tail = NULL;  // end of list
   int size,i;
   printf("Enter Size of List : ");
   scanf("%d",&size);

   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
      // Creating first node
      if(i==0)
      {
         a_head=a_tail=malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
         getValue(a_tail);
      }
      // Creating other nodes
      else
      {
         a_tail->next=malloc(sizeof(myStruct)); // adding new node to the end of non-empty list
         getValue(a_tail->next); // Insert data into the new node
         a_tail=a_tail->next; // update tail pointer
      }
   }
return a_head;
}
```

Comment: The major problem with this is that it does not handle early EOF gracefully.  Otherwise, it looks right — I'd keep the tail pointer (as well as the head pointer) to make additions at the tail easy too.

Answer (score 0):

Inside that `for` loop you should somehow create the nodes you need (probably asking the user for input and using `malloc()` as you say), and then link from the previous one. In this case you would want to keep a pointer to the last element of the list, as that would be the one that would point to the new one when it gets linked.

An academic-but-functional implementation of this can be found in [this project at my University](https://github.com/sisoputnfrba/so-commons-library/blob/master/src/commons/collections/list.c#L42).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
 struct N
 {
  int Data;
  struct N *Next;
 };
 typedef struct N node;
 node *H, *T;
 char C[100];
 H=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 T=H;
 printf("Enter numbers to create and store in Linked List, to stop storing enter 'X': ");
 while(1)
      {
       scanf("%s", C);
       if(C[0]!=' ')
         {
          if(C[0]!='X')
            {
             T->Data=atoi(C);
             T->Next=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
             T=T->Next;
             T->Next=NULL;
            }
          else
            break;
         }
      }
 T=H;
 printf("The elements in the Linked List are:");
 while(T->Next!=NULL)
      {
       printf(" %d", T->Data);
       T=T->Next;
      }
 printf(".\n");
 free(H);
 free(T);
}
```